# Distance between Yorktown and the unexplored planet

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In [Star Trek Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660888/), the crew of the USS Enterprise are asked to carry out a search and rescue mission on an unexplored planet relatively close to the space station "Yorktown".

Given that the Enterprise has to travel some time to get there -- presumably with its warp drive -- the unexplored planet must be located quite far away from the space station. Yet, the "bees" are able to get to Yorktown in "no time". Surely no ships that size have warp drive? If warp drive is needed to get back to Yorktown in good time, shouldn't the crew have arrived long before the bees did?

Comment: The bees were already there. In the final captain's log, he mentions that there is an indigenous civilization that has the technology to prolong life.

Comment: @sanpaco Yes, the bees were found on the planet, yet they seem perfectly capable of leaving the nebula and reaching at least as far as Yorktown at least as fast as the Franklin.

Comment: If you have more questions, please ask them separately.

Comment: Plenty of ships that size have warp drives. Not saying those did, but many do.

Comment: @cde If those small ships have warp, then the stranded crew wouldn't have been stranded for so long. If they don't have warp, then the main crew should have arrived at Yorktown before them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: They may have warp as Jayla says they search the stars for their death machine